# Do the AIs know I'm not one of them?

Tags: civilization-5

Sometimes it feels that the Artificial Intelligence players of Civilization V are just picking on me.

But after playing a bit more, I think it may be just observation bias, e.g. I *know* every time they backstab me, but don't know every time they backstab each other...

So, does anyone know if these AI's know which is the human player?

That could be either through a big "human" tatoo on my forehead, or by inescapable analysis such as measuring how long I take to answer a diplomatic proposition.

Comment: Do Civilization AIs Dream of Squishy Human Players?

Comment: It seems like they treat everyone the same... After all, they ask the player also to join them in war and to trade and all that stuff. I think their attitude towards you and all the positive and negative stuff, along with what they need to win accounts for their attitude towards you.

Comment: Yes, yes they know... and they know you're playing in underwear (or not)! Don't wonder why past that point..

Comment: The only reason I see this making sense is with difficulty levels, otherwise it just complicates the development process of the game. Say the game gets harder, then maybe the AI are programmed to gang up on you more, although I'm NOT saying this is how it works. As for "how" (if they do). It's almost certainly a "stamp" determined beforehand and not judged my how long you take to decide stuff. Just think, the AI NEVER sees the diplomatic dialogs, it all happens "behind the scenes". They show you because you're a human player.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer to this is: Yes, the AI knows you are not one of them. From a programming point of view you have to remember that an AI doesn't think, it's only constructed in way that you have the feeling of talking to a "real" player.

So as a matter of fact, the AI players treat you differently since the game is constructed to be appealing to you, not the other AIs. There will be variables to calculate how they interact with each other base on "personality" traits the received, but keep in mind this is only simulated interaction.

When the AI interacts with you, there is something that is really difficult to simulate, which is your human factor. Opposing to the other AIs it doesn't know your personality traits, etc. so from a bare programming point of view it even has to treat you differently.

It's also quite possible that the other "players" don't have a live on their own and that it's in fact just one AI that simulates their interactions and make it look to you like they are individuals.

Summary: It's highly likely the AI is treating you different, but also it's likely that it's supposed to look like that's it's not.